# SQL select row if column equal to row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, row, multiple-columns

I got this table:

```
| NINumber  | fname | lname   | mentored_by |
---------------------------------------------
| DD1199XYZ | John  | Smith   | DD234CD1X   |
| DD0094CYY | Barry | Gibbson | DD0094CYY   |
| DD234CD1X | Mike  | Hammer  | NULL        |
| AB2323CYA | Peter | Falk    | NULL        |
```

Basically I'm trying to find the person that is not mentored by anyone but is a mentor to someone. And display their NINumber, initial of their first name and last name.

For example from my table I should get the person with:

```
| DD234CD1X | Mike  | Hammer  | NULL        |
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT NINumber, SUBSTRING(fname, 1, 1) AS init, lname 
FROM Hospital_Doctor
WHERE NINumber IN (
 SELECT NINumber 
 FROM Hospital_Doctor 
 where IFNULL(mentored_by, 'NULL') = 'NULL' 
)
```

This basically shows the persons that are not mentored by anyone but I can't figure how am I supposed to show that a person is also a mentor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exists` with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from Hospital_Doctor t
where 
    t.mentored_by is null
    and exists (
        select 1 from Hospital_Doctor t1 where t1.mentored_by = t.NINumber
    )
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d21d0c09f31d053b9032e7dfcc704ac)**:

```
NINumber  | fname | lname  | mentored_by
:-------- | :---- | :----- | :----------
DD234CD1X | Mike  | Hammer | null
```

Comment: What does "select 1" actually do, it works but I just want to understand why

Comment: @NikuNik: the purpose of the `exists` condition is to check whether the subquery returns *something*. So basically the results of the subquery are discarded, hence the `select 1`.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use `exists`, `INNER JOIN` will be faster

```
select d.NINumber, SUBSTRING(d.fname, 1, 1) AS init, d.lname
from Hospital_Doctor d
inner join Hospital_Doctor md on md.mentored_by = d.NINumber
where d.mentored_by is null;
```

Comment: If a person has no mentor but mentors more than one person, this will produce duplicate rows.

Comment: Agree with duplicate rows, completely disagree with @danblack. Inner join also does filtering here and if you remove it you lose this filtering.